# create list of dataframes matching a pattern

Tags: r, pattern-matching

This is a very simple question, however I can't seem to come up w/ an answer. I would like to create a list of `data frames` matching a pattern, then `rm` these from the global environment.

The pattern to match is '`water_land_by_owntype_*`'

This is what I have tried, but it doesn't work...I think b/c it doesn't know where to search for the string.

```
rm (matches <- list(
    grep('water_land_by_owntype_*')))
```

-al

Comment: How to make sure that all objects that are found are data frames?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hi you can do like this :

```
# Create some data.frame
water_land_by_owntype_1 <- mtcars
water_land_by_owntype_2 <- mtcars
water_land_by_owntype_3 <- mtcars
water_land_by_owntype_4 <- mtcars
water_land_by_owntype_5 <- mtcars

# Put them in a list
water_land_by_owntype <- lapply(ls(pattern = "water_land_by_owntype_.*"), get)

# or more directly
water_land_by_owntype <- mget(ls(pattern = "water_land_by_owntype_.*"))

# Delete them
rm(list = ls(pattern = "water_land_by_owntype_.*"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be the simplest way to do it.
1. Extract variables by ls()
2. Detect (return boolean) pattern
3. Locate and subset
4. Remove

```
library(stringr)
a = ls()
index = which(str_detect(ls, "water_land_by_owntype_"))
b = a[index]
rm(b)
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Even more simplier : `rm(list = ls(pattern = "water_land_by_owntype_.*"))`